# Match any patterns with in {}

Tags: r, regex

I'm using R and I have the following text:

```
text<-"\n\n\n\n\nThe Project Gutenberg eBook of Moby Dick; Or the Whale, by Herman Melville\n\n\n\n    body {margin-left:15%; margin-right:15%; text-align:justify }\n    p { text-indent: 1em; margin-top: .25em; margin-bottom: .25em; }\n    H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6 { text-align: center; margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 15%; }\n    hr  { width: 50%; text-align: center;}\n    blockquote {font-size: 100%; margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%;}\n    .mynote    {background-color: #DDE; color: #000; padding: .5em; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 95%;}\n    .toc       { margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: .75em;}\n    pre        { font-family: times new roman; font-size: 100%; margin-left: 10%;}\n\n"
```

I want to remove all patterns within {} and all words that starts with .

for example I would like that the following will be removed:
"{margin-left:15%; margin-right:15%; text-align:justify }"
.toc
.25em

tried the following regex:

```
gsub('{.*?}', "",text)
gsub('^[.]\w*', "",text)
```

but R returns an error.

Comment: Read in the [plain text version](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt) and skip the hassle of stripping out the CSS and other elements from the HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape regex *metacharacters* such as `{`.  According to R's [documentation on regular expressions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html):

> Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash. The metacharacters in extended regular expressions are ‘⁠. \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?⁠’, but note that whether these have a special meaning depends on the context.

Beyond this, your patterns have some issues.  Consider using this version:

```r
text <- "\n\n\n\n\nThe Project Gutenberg eBook of Moby Dick; Or the Whale, by Herman Melville\n\n\n\n    body {margin-left:15%; margin-right:15%; text-align:justify }\n    p { text-indent: 1em; margin-top: .25em; margin-bottom: .25em; }\n    H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6 { text-align: center; margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 15%; }\n    hr  { width: 50%; text-align: center;}\n    blockquote {font-size: 100%; margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%;}\n    .mynote    {background-color: #DDE; color: #000; padding: .5em; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 95%;}\n    .toc       { margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: .75em;}\n    pre        { font-family: times new roman; font-size: 100%; margin-left: 10%;}\n\n"
text <- gsub('\\{.*?\\}|(?<!\\S)\\.\\S+', "", text, perl=TRUE)
text

[1] "\n\n\n\n\nThe Project Gutenberg eBook of Moby Dick; Or the Whale, by Herman Melville\n\n\n\n    body \n    p \n    H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6 \n    hr  \n    blockquote \n        \n           \n    pre        \n\n"
```

Note that I have also escaped `\}` despite it not being required.  Some regex flavors will require this, and from a portability point of view, escaping both `{` and `}` may have an advantage.

Comment: In a TRE regex that OP uses, the `{` outside the character class must be escaped, the `}` is not any special regex metacharacter (neither in TRE, nor in PCRE). In a PCRE regex, `{.*?}` does not need escaping at all as this regex engine is smart enough to parse `{` and `}` in this context as literal chars. `gsub('{.*?}|(?<!\\S)\\.\\S+', '', text, perl=TRUE)` [works well](https://ideone.com/GxSmL4), too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I just learned something new.  Here is a smiley face using curly braces: `\:-}` ... and I did not need to escape the curly brace.